# How can I use a stored procedure MySQL in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to solve a problem: When user click on delete a record and instead of delete it, this record will change status to `'false'`.

I suppose to create stored procedures in MySQL like `"getAllUser"`, `"changeStatus"` but I'm confusing what I have to do.

This is structure of my project:

```
-configuration
 JpaConfiguration
-controller
 RestApiController
-model
 User
-Repository
 UserRepository
-Service
 UserService
 UserServiceImpl
```

Then I expect the index page only get records that have status is `'true'`.

1. Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllUsers`()
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM APP_USER where status = 0;
    END
```

2. RestApiController

```
     @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/api")
        public class RestApiController {
        @Autowired
            UserService userService;
            @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public List<User> getAllUsers(Boolean status){
                Boolean statusWhere = org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils.isNotTrue(false);
                List<User> users = userServiceImpl.getAllUsers(statusWhere);
                if (users == null){
                    return new ArrayList<>();
                } else {
                    return users;
                }
            }
        // Change status
        @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
            public ResponseEntity<?>deleteUserById(@PathVariable("id") long id){
                logger.info("Delete User with id {}", id);
                User currentUser = userService.findById(id);
                currentUser.setStatus(true);
                return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
```

3. model/User

```
    @Entity
    @NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
            @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                    name = "getAllUsers",
                    procedureName = "getAllUsers",
                    resultClasses = {User.class},
                    parameters = {
                            @StoredProcedureParameter(
                                    mode = ParameterMode.IN,
                                    name = "status",
                                    type = Boolean.class)
                    }
            )
    })
```

4. service/UserServiceImpl

```
     @Component
            @Service("userService")
            @Transactional
            public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
                @Autowired
                private EntityManager entityManager;
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                public List<User> getAllUsers(Boolean status){
                    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = this.entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getAllUsers");
                    storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("status",status);
                    storedProcedureQuery.execute();
                    return storedProcedureQuery.getResultList();
                }
                public boolean isUserExist(User user) {
                    return findByName(user.getName()) != null;
                }
              }
```

Comment: please share your code which you have tried

Comment: what happens when you run your code? it looks pretty ok to me

Comment: Thanks for edited my post. I posted my code above. I'm a newbie so i'm not really understand all my code, just follow guideline. Whatever you can help me solve this problem, thank you for answer!

Comment: My change status function (in RestApiController) not active. I still dont know why :(